# Open a py file from pressing a button on another py file

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm coding a game using wxpython with multiple *.py scripts and I would like to, when I press a button from the main script, another script is launched.

Example: I launch a *.py script for the game menu window that has multiple options. When I press the options button, it will launch an other script that was assigned to that button an open the options window

How can I do that? Thx

Comment: You don't want to open another Python script, you want to open a new window.

Comment: rather than running another script, import the other files into your main script and call the functions you need from within the same .py file.

Comment: well I have 1 script for 1 window so in order to open another window I need to open the script. I can open each script alone but I don't want to load all the files from the terminal. I only want to load the main script from the terminal and then open the other from th main script

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: thx for the link. by using from file import *, I can load the other files but it has to be in the same folder. What I would like if possible is to open the scripts that are placed in another folder
example: mainmenu.py in on c:/python and options.py n c:/python/resources.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of launching another *.py file when clicking the button, you should rethink how you organize your code. Separating each window into different python scripts is probably not the way to go. This requires you to do some messy stuff with subprocesses and you'll probably end up with a ton of race conditions.

A better way would be to [organize your code into modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html), import them into your main program, and call them when needed.

For example, if you put everything to do with the configuration of your game in a `settings` module and imported it, instead of telling the OS to run the script using the Python interpreter, you could just call `settings.show_window()` from your main program.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using subprocess?

you can assign button event to subprocess to launch another py script.

Comment: Unfortunately implementing this via subprocess will complicate the asker's problem.

Comment: how will it complicate the problem? the OP wants to launch another window by pressing another button located on a different window..

Comment: How will it get the selected options back to the main program?

Answer (score 0):

well i'd recommend using `os` module for only in case you want to run an script till it's closed ,Or in other words like making the main script in the ground and focus in the option window

use `os.system('script_name.py'`) < in windows

or `os.system('python script.py')` < in Linux after giving it the permission

Comment: sir i've read your question and my answer based on my understanding to your question

Answer (score 0):

Launching a new Python script is typically done using os.system or subprocess, however it sounds like all you want to do is open another frame or dialog in wxPython. If so, then just put all your secondary frame code into a separate file and import it into the main file. Then instantiate the frame in the main frame's button event handler and show it. The same applies if you're showing a dialog. You can see the general idea of showing a secondary frame here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/ (although it hides the main frame in that example).